# Update dictionary inside of dictionary without deleting contents

Tags: python

I'm looping through a data set, and updating a dictionary as needed.  As a precursor to the dictionary update, I have a "default" dictionary "template" like so:

```
databody_item = {'name': 'Kermit',
                'interests': {
                                'test1':True,
                             },
                }
```

I want to update the interests dictionary inside of the databody_item dictionary, so I run:

```
databody_item.update({'interests':{'test2':True}})
```

This however cleared the entire interests dict, leaving me with this:

```
{'interests': {'test2': True}, 'name': 'Kermit'}
```

However, I need the dictionary to be updated like this:

```
{'interests': {'test1': True, 'test2': True}, 'name': 'Kermit'}
```

Comment: What you want to do is `databody_item['interests'].update({'test2': True})`. Or just `databody_item['interests']['test2'] = True`.

Comment: If you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do, and why you thought `update` was necessary for the task, we can probably either find  a dup or write a complete answer that explains things to you better.

Comment: @abarnert thanks so much.  Your first suggestion helped.  I searched for dictionary inside of dictionary, but never thought to reference it as a nested dictionary.  The question this one was marked as a duplicate of resolved the issue, as well does your response.