# Update dictionary inside of dictionary when key is already present

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I know there are variations of this question already present and I have already gone through them. Specifically, the questions I went through are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118687/updating-nested-dictionaries-when-data-has-existing-key) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49926727/update-dictionary-inside-of-dictionary-without-deleting-contents). I have tried using all the solutions listed but it really doesn't work for me since in my case I have to iterate through the other dictionary and many a times the keys within the dict of dict will also be the same(in which case the value should become a list.Let me illustrate with an example:

Lets say `entity_sentiment_dictionary` is the dictionary I want to append to from `entity_sentiment_int_int_dict`

```
entity_sentiment_dictionary = {  'name': {'userid1': 0.0},
 'Aditya': {'userid1': 0.0},
 'Glen': {'5dad13fc54aeb500078637e0': -0.10000000149011612},
 'Kenta': {'5dad13fc54aeb500078637e0': 0.0},
 'Keita': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
 'Ganchan': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
 'Anna': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
 'Joe': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.8999999761581421}}

entity_sentiment_int_int_dict = {  'name': {'userid1': 0.1},
                                  'Aditya': {'userid2': 0.3}}
```

When I update, the result should be something like this:

```
entity_sentiment_dictionary = {  'name': {'userid1': [0.0,0.1]},
     'Aditya': {'userid1': 0.0, 'userid2': 0.3},
     'Glen': {'5dad13fc54aeb500078637e0': -0.10000000149011612},
     'Kenta': {'5dad13fc54aeb500078637e0': 0.0},
     'Keita': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
     'Ganchan': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
     'Anna': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
     'Joe': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.8999999761581421}}
```

This is where I have gotten to so far after trying out all the methods I could find online:

```
for key in entity_sentiment_int_int_dict.keys():
        if key in entity_sentiment_dictionary:
            for k in entity_sentiment_dictionary.keys():
                if key==k:
                    entity_sentiment_dictionary[key][k] = dict(entity_sentiment_int_int_dict[key])
        else:
            entity_sentiment_dictionary[key] = entity_sentiment_int_int_dict[key]
```

It yields me the result:

```
{'name': {'usedid1': 0.0,'name': {'userid1': 0.1}},
 'Aditya': {'userid1': 0.0, 'Aditya': {'userid2': 0.5} },
 'Glen': {'5dad13fc54aeb500078637e0': -0.10000000149011612},
 'Kenta': {'5dad13fc54aeb500078637e0': 0.0},
 'Keita': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
 'Ganchan': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
 'Anna': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
 'Joe': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.8999999761581421}}
```

I feel like I'm almost there and need to make a change to the nested for loop. Any help is appreciated and any other way to get the intended result is also recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
for k, v in entity_sentiment_int_int_dict.items():
    if k in entity_sentiment_dictionary.keys():
        entry = entity_sentiment_dictionary[k]
        for update_key, update_val in v.items():
            if update_key in entry:
                if isinstance(entry[update_key], list):
                    entry[update_key].append(update_val)
                else:
                    entry[update_key] = [entry[update_key], update_val]
            else:
                entry[update_key] = update_val

# with 'out' as desired output dict from OP:
entity_sentiment_dictionary == out  # True
```

Complete code to reproduce:

```
entity_sentiment_dictionary = {  'name': {'userid1': 0.0},
 'Aditya': {'userid1': 0.0},
 'Glen': {'5dad13fc54aeb500078637e0': -0.10000000149011612},
 'Kenta': {'5dad13fc54aeb500078637e0': 0.0},
 'Keita': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
 'Ganchan': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
 'Anna': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
 'Joe': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.8999999761581421}}

entity_sentiment_int_int_dict = {  'name': {'userid1': 0.1},
                                  'Aditya': {'userid2': 0.3}}

out = {'name': {'userid1': [0.0,0.1]},
     'Aditya': {'userid1': 0.0, 'userid2': 0.3},
     'Glen': {'5dad13fc54aeb500078637e0': -0.10000000149011612},
     'Kenta': {'5dad13fc54aeb500078637e0': 0.0},
     'Keita': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
     'Ganchan': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
     'Anna': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
     'Joe': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.8999999761581421}}

for k, v in entity_sentiment_int_int_dict.items():
    if k in entity_sentiment_dictionary.keys():
        entry = entity_sentiment_dictionary[k]
        for update_key, update_val in v.items():
            if update_key in entry:
                if isinstance(entry[update_key], list):
                    entry[update_key].append(update_val)
                else:
                    entry[update_key] = [entry[update_key], update_val]
            else:
                entry[update_key] = update_val
```

Assertion test and actual output:

```
print(f"Result matches desired output: {entity_sentiment_dictionary == out}")
# Result matches desired output: True

entity_sentiment_dictionary

{'name': {'userid1': [0.0, 0.1]},
 'Aditya': {'userid1': 0.0, 'userid2': 0.3},
 'Glen': {'5dad13fc54aeb500078637e0': -0.10000000149011612},
 'Kenta': {'5dad13fc54aeb500078637e0': 0.0},
 'Keita': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
 'Ganchan': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
 'Anna': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.0},
 'Joe': {'5dd23a18c7949300087d8d88': 0.8999999761581421}}
```

Comment: Hmm. it yields an empty dictionary. I am initializing 'entry' outside the for loop. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not sure - I just used the code  you posted in your question.  Just added everything for a complete reproducible solution.

Comment: Re `entry`, if you have a different variable called `entry` in your code that might cause an issue.  Can you reproduce if you run the code in my answer in a clean environment?

Comment: Hey I figured it out. The code you posted earlier works. it was just missing another else block which I added

Comment: The else block for the first if statement was missing for cases when key doesn't already exist.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.  I didn't include that because your example output doesn't actually have that edge case.  But if you want to either (a) update your original post with a testable edge case for this condition, or (b) just tell me what you want that extra `else` to do, I'd be happy to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you require.
Can be optimised further.

```
for key in entity_sentiment_int_int_dict.keys():
    if key in entity_sentiment_dictionary.keys():
        if entity_sentiment_dictionary[key].keys() == entity_sentiment_int_int_dict[key].keys():
            temp = []
            temp.append(next(iter(entity_sentiment_dictionary[key].values())))
            temp.append(next(iter(entity_sentiment_int_int_dict[key].values())))
            entity_sentiment_dictionary[key][next(iter(entity_sentiment_dictionary[key].keys()))] = temp
        else:
            entity_sentiment_dictionary[key].update(entity_sentiment_int_int_dict[key])
    else:
        entity_sentiment_dictionary.update(entity_sentiment_int_int_dict[key])
```

Output
[image]

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to build a list just to retrieve the first value... just use `next(iter(<dict>.values()))` instead; much more efficient.

Comment: @JordanBrière Thanks for your suggestion, I was looking for something like this. Updated the answer!